# "Может(,) и есть" — запятая после "может"

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова

— Тут нет того, что я ищу.
— Может(,) и есть, — сказала она.

Нужна ли запятая после "может"?

Answer (score 3):

Конечно нужна! Это вводное слово. Не кто-то же что-то может.

Comment: Разве тут не "и" - не усилительная частица при вводном слове "может"? Есть правило, что они не разделяются. А если убрать "может" из предл - то звучит ерундово:  — Тут нет того, что я ищу. — И есть, — сказала она.

Comment: Нет, это совсем не усилительная частица. Да и стоит **после** вводного слова.

Comment: Можно дополнить: «Не кто-то же что-то может есть».

Comment: @shampar: верно, так тоже может быть. А я думал про однородные члены (кто-то может и что-то имеется). Но Ваш случай действительно проще и менее надуманный. ;)

Comment: Есть такое правило, но это не усилительная частица.

Comment: Это не союз (что здесь соединяется?), поэтому частица.

Comment: Союз И может стоять в начале предложения, между простыми предложениями или между однородными элементами.

Comment: Ну то есть да, усилительная частица, видимо, но относится-то она не к вводному слову, а к *есть.* Я это именно в виду.

Comment: *имел то есть в виду